# Can't catch quiz questions ids

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update quiz but i don't know how to catch questions ids.
But just for now i'm getting General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '["1","1","1"]' for column 'correct'  and it's changing quiz name section and second question i can't catch question ids...

```php
public function update(Request $r)
{
    // quiz
    $quizId = $r->get('quizId');
    $name = $r->get('name');
    $section = $r->get('sectionId');

    // questions
    $questionId = $r->get('questionId');
    $question = $r->get('question');

    // answers
    $answerId = $r->get('answerId');
    $answer = $r->get('answer');
    $correct = $r->get('correct');

    CourseQuiz::where('id', $quizId)->update([
        'name' => $name,
        'section_id' => $section
    ]);

    foreach ($question as $q) {
        CourseQuestion::where('id', $questionId)->update([
            'question' => $q,
        ]);
    }
    foreach ($answer as $a) {
        CourseAnswer::where('id', $answerId)->update([
            'answer' => $a,
            'correct' => $correct
        ]);
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

blade

```xml
@foreach($q->questions as $qu)
    <div class="p-2">
        <input hidden type="text" name="questionId" value="{{ $qu->id }}">
        question: <input type="text" name="question[]" value="{{ $qu->question }}">
    </div>
    @foreach($qu->answers as $a)
        <input hidden type="text" name="answerId" value="{{ $a->id }}">
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $a->correct }}" name="correct[]" @if($a->correct !== 0) class="active form-check-input" checked @else class="form-check-input" @endif>
        answer: <input type="text" name="answer[]" value="{{ $a->answer }}">
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: btw, the method for retrieving input from the request in Laravel is `input` not `get` ... the input "correct" is an array, how are you expecting that to be inserted into a field?

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake. i'm new in laravel. but it does not save questions and answers why?

Comment: Also, you are defining the `questionId` and `asnwerId` form elements repeatedly; only the last one in the loop will be received by your server. This doesn't make sense if you're passing the other values as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the id of the question/answer as a key in the name attribute of the inputs.

```xml
@foreach($q->questions as $qu)
    <div class="p-2">
        question: <input type="text" name="q[{{ $qu->id }}][question]" value="{{ $qu->question }}">
    </div>
    @foreach($qu->answers as $a)
        <input type="checkbox" name="a[{{ $a->id }}][correct]" value="{{ $a->correct }}" class="form-check-input {{ $a->correct !== 0 ? 'active" checked' : '"' }}>
        answer: <input type="text" name="a[{{ $a->id }}][answer]" value="{{ $a->answer }}">
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

This would group the inputs a little bit.

```
q[1][question]
a[1][correct]
a[1][answer]
a[2][correct]
a[2][answer]
a[3][correct]
a[3][answer]
a[4][correct]
a[4][answer]
a[5][correct]
a[5][answer]
q[2][question]
...
```

```php
foreach ($r->q as $key => $value) {
    CourseQuestion::where('id', $key)->update([
        'question' => $value['question'],
    ]);
}

foreach ($r->a as $key => $value) {
    CourseAnswer::where('id', $key)->update([
        'answer' => $value['answer'],
        'correct' => $value['correct']
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for response. I'm getting Undefined array key "correct" error now.

Comment: Ah, right. Since it's a checkbox the logic has to be a little different. Try `'correct' => isset($value['correct']) ? true : false`